# Scala Play 2.5: Is it possible to bypass (defer) body parsing when using Action Composition?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have several layers of ActionFunctions for api service, e.g. authorization and rate limiting. After implementing a file upload I realized that I'd really like authorization and rate limiting to happen before the file is uploaded, not after.

(I built a custom body parser for a file uploading, but let's say I have a giant json - why to parse it it's thrown away?)

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with the `ActionFunction`s, as you said they use parsers to parse the body before the checks are done. 
You can have checks before the parsing of the body by using `EssentialAction`. But you'll need to re-implement the logic of the compositions